# Possible to Create Project Choosing either Silverlight 3 or 2

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

On my computer according to 'Add Remove Programs' I have  installed:
  Microsoft Silverlight
  Microsoft Silverlight 2 SDK
  Microsoft Silverlight 2 Toolkit July 2009
  Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK
  Microsoft Silverlight 3 Toolkit July 2009
  Microsoft Silverlight 3 Tools for VS 2008 SP1-ENU

When I create a Silverlight project, I am guessing it creates it using Silverlight 3.

Is there a way to verify this?

Also, I am new to Silverlight and have found that most of the tutorials, videos, books etc are still geared to Silverlilght 2.  When I try to use them, they do not work - it seems like I cannot follow the steps because I am seeing something different on my screen than what they say I should be seeing, and I can't get any farther.  This has been a real problem in trying to understand data access.

Is there a way to choose, when starting a new project, which Silverlight version to use, or do I need to uninstall version 3 if I want to use version 2?

Thanks
Mike Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Telling which has been created was previously covered [Anyway to tell if project is in Silverlight 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219315/anyway-to-tell-if-project-is-in-silverlight-3/1219368#1219368) by looking in the .csproj files.

Just the latest Silverlight Tools version will be used with both installed, when creating new projects, but you should be able to save a relatively empty project to use as a template if you're doing multi-version development usually.

You could just change the  statement in the project file after creating a SL3 one, but there may be some small differences in the project (Page renamed to MainPage, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but one way to tell what runtime your Silverlight project is targeting is the the markup for the Silverlight tag in the host aspx page.

param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" == Silverlight2
param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" == Silverlight3